# how to write a mass email in apex code i have tried if any know what error in this can u solve this

Tags: apex, email

```
public PageReference send()
    {
        List<Contact> contacts=[Select Id,Email From Contact Where AccountId='001i000000g7erl'];
        List<Id> Conids=new List<string>();
        for(Contact mail: contacts)
        {
            Conids.add(mail.Email);
        }
        //String[] address=new String[]{'Conids'};
        Messaging.MassEmailMessage emails=new Messaging.MassEmailMessage(); 
        emails.setTargetObjectIds(Conids);
        emails.setTemplateId('00Xi0000000J9hx');
        emails.setsubject('note');
        //emails.setplainTextBody('body');
        //emails.setToaddress(address);
        Messaging.SendEmail(New Messaging.MassEmailMessage[] {emails});

return null;
}
```

this my error::System.StringException: Invalid id: vivek@gmail.com
Error is in expression '{!send}' in component  in page brand

Answer (score 5):

Here is something closer to what you would need. There are definately some best practice updates such as bulkifying your process so that you can send a list of accounts to the method, querying for a map so that you can eliminate a loop, and querying for the email template rather than hard coding an id.

```
    public PageReference send(List<Account> accountIds)
    {
        Map<Id, Contact> contactMap = new Map<Id, Contact>([SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :accountIds]);

        EmailTemplate template =  [SELECT Id, Name FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = 'My_Unique_API_Name' LIMIT 1];

        Messaging.MassEmailMessage emails=new Messaging.MassEmailMessage(); 
        emails.setTargetObjectIds(contactMap.keySet());
        emails.setTemplateId(template.Id);
        emails.setsubject('note');
        Messaging.SendEmail(New Messaging.MassEmailMessage[]{emails});

        return null;
    }
```

Remember to select this as an answer if it corrects the issue you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what line the error is being thrown at but you are doing two things incorrectly:

You have a mismatch of types here:

```
List<Id> Conids = new List<String>();
```

`setTargetObjectIds` is expecting a list of contact Ids but you are passing in a list of emails. See the [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_mass.htm#apex_Messaging_MassEmailMessage_setTargetObjectIds) for more information on it.

You should be doing something like this:

```
public PageReference send() {
        List<Contact> contacts=[Select Id From Contact Where AccountId='001i000000g7erl'];
        List<Id> conIds=new List<Id>();
        for(Contact c: contacts) {
            conIds.add(c.Id);
        }

        Messaging.MassEmailMessage email = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage(); 
        email.setTargetObjectIds(conIds);
        email.setTemplateId('00Xi0000000J9hx');
        email.setSubject('note');
        Messaging.SendEmail(New Messaging.MassEmailMessage[] {email});

        return null;
}
```

Comment: And of course there is the obvious thing to point that you have hardcoded Ids in the code so this code will only work as expected in the org where those Ids are valid.

Comment: thanks for code but if i use List<Id> conIds=new List<Id>(); my getting the same error like this::System.StringException: Invalid id: vivek@gmail.com
Error is in expression '{!send}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page brand

Comment: What line of code is throwing that error? Are you sure you are adding Id rather than Email to the conIds List?